# doctrine mongodb odm map reduce

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm

Is it possible after a Map/Reduce with Doctrine to get a collection of entities ?

According to the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/mongodb_odm/1.0/en/reference/map-reduce.html) we get an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [another page of the document](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/mongodb_odm/1.0/en/reference/query-builder-api.html) where it's written:

> When you specify a map() and reduce() operation the results will not be hydrated and the raw results from the map reduce operation will be returned.

So I think the response is no ...

I also found that I can use where($javascript) to do what I want.

Comment: sorry it is a dead link now